Send email with ms graph API with attached eml file results in error on recipient side
I am able to send an email with attachments using the ms graph api (version 6.4.0) in java. However, when I add an eml file as attachment, this file cannot be previewed in Gmail or any other email client except Outlook.
I set the contentType of the attachment to message/rfc822 but when I view the message that was received I see that the contentType is application/octet-stream. I believe that this is the issue that Gmail cannot preview the file. Instead of a preview I get the popup with an error message stating: "an error occurred while loading the attached message".
Another weird thing is that when I forward the mail from Gmail to myself, in that forwarded mail, I can open the attached eml file as a preview.
I have extracted a minimal part of code that sends an email with attachment.


import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.*;
import com.microsoft.graph.serviceclient.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.users.item.sendmail.SendMailPostRequestBody;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

public class GraphSendMail {
    private static final String USER = "user@domain.be";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("clientId")
                .tenantId("tenantId")
                .clientSecret("clientSecret")
                .build();

        var client = new GraphServiceClient(credential, "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

        var sendMailRequest = new SendMailPostRequestBody();

        Message message = new Message();

        Recipient to = new Recipient();
        to.setEmailAddress(new EmailAddress());
        to.getEmailAddress().setAddress("receiver@gmail.com");
        message.setToRecipients(List.of(to));

        var sender = new Recipient();
        sender.setEmailAddress(new EmailAddress());
        sender.getEmailAddress().setAddress(USER);

        message.setSender(sender);
        message.setFrom(sender);
        message.setSubject("Test mail");

        // Send HTML email
        ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
        body.setContentType(BodyType.Html);
        body.setContent("<html><body><h1>Test body</h1></body></html>");
        message.setBody(body);

        String filePath = "C:/pathtofile/attached-mail.eml"; // Specify the path to your file
        File file = new File(filePath);
        byte[] fileBytes = readFileToByteArray(file);
        fileBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileBytes);

        FileAttachment attachment = new FileAttachment();
        attachment.setName("attached-mail.eml");
        attachment.setContentBytes(fileBytes);
        attachment.setContentType("message/rfc822");

        message.setAttachments(List.of(attachment));

        sendMailRequest.setMessage(message);

        client.users()
                .byUserId(USER)
                .sendMail()
                .post(sendMailRequest);

        System.out.println("Mail sent success");
    }

    public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        byte[] byteArray = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fis.read(byteArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}



I attempted the same with javax.mail and an smtp server and that works fine. However smtp is not an option for this project.
I don't think I should be using an ItemAttachment because the eml can be stored on disk and it is possible that is was never in Outlook to begin with so I would have no reference to it.

Please add a [mre]

@LarsNielsen I have added a full working code snippet except for the credentials and email addresses.
